# How to get first word in map with Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to get the first word **server1** and **server2** in the map bellow. How I can do that with groovy?

```
[{server1={ansible_host=server1}, server2={test=test}}]
```

In the end I want to get only **server1** and **server2**

Answer (score 1):

```
def map = [server1:[host:'server1.com']]
def result = map.keySet().first()​​​​​​​

assert result == 'server1'
```